# JavaFX: detect if application is embedded in a browser

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to programmatically detect if JavaFX application is running in a browser(is embedded) or is running as a standalone application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it, by: Application.getHostServices().getWebContext();

public final JSObject getWebContext();
Returns the JavaScript handle of the enclosing DOM window of the web page containing this application. This handle is used to access the web page by calling from Java into JavaScript. If the application is not embedded into a web page, this method return null.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html